# Linked list of different classes, how to access specific class functions with pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, linked-list

Ok so I have a linked list of Personnel.  However, I can add to the list a Personnel, an Employee, a Faculty, or a Student, because the other 3 are child classes.

Teacher directions: "Add a sub menu item and related functions (insert book) to allow a new book to be added into the book tree of an existing student node. The new book must be inserted into the correct place to maintain the binary search tree feature. The information of student name, book title, and url must be entered. To simply the program, you can assume that all the nodes in the linked list are Student nodes."

^^ ** I want to point out that I see where she says to simplify assume all the linked lists are student nodes, but all of the code for Personnel/Employee/Faculty and the linked list is supplied in the assignment.  So, the only way to "use" that I can think of is go through all the code any change any reference from Personnel to Student, but that seems like a fairly stupid assignment at that point...

So my problem: I need to go through the linked list until I find the right entry using only name field.  But then I need to edit the BookTree class that is tied to that entry, which only the child class Student has.  I can't loop through the linked list with a Student pointer (although, the list is empty of anything other than students) because of type mismatch w/ Personnel, but if I find it by using a Personnel pointer I, of course, won't have access to Student specific functions to edit what I need to.

I have tried Student *ptr = &PersonnelPtr to just assign it the address after I located the correct one, no dice.

The code:

```
int add_book()
{
    char studentName[50]; // blah
    PersonnelNode *temp, *prev;
    Student *student;       
    temp = head;
    prev = temp;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        student = temp->getNode(); // this line gives "value of type Personnel* cannot be assigned to an entity of type Student*
        if (_stricmp(studentName, student->getName()) != 0) 
        {
            prev = temp; // loop through
            temp = temp->getNext();
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do Stuff
            // More importantly in the do stuff part I need access to Student-specific data/functions that Personnel pointer won't see
```

Comment: is `Personel` derived from `Student`? If yes, do they implement a common interface via virtual functions?

Comment: Personnel is the parent.  Personnel > Employee > Faculty  and Personnel > Student

Comment: It seems that you have to cast :( `Student* student = dynamic_cast<Student*>(tempNode);`

Comment: But then later when I need to add books to the student, Personnel pointer will error.  So I'm not sure how to use that.  However I think I can solve the problem with virtual functions either way, almost done trying that

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, thanks @vsoftco I can't figure out how to mark it as answered, probably cuz you just answered in a comment lol

Comment: @DannyRandolph Your question was not very clear (I mean, not enough information), and that's why I commented on it. In general, I strongly prefer writing answers (no comments). Posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a pointer to `Personnel` to control the other entities (children). Right now you're doing the other way around, and the compiler tells you that the right hand side (a `Personnel*`) cannot be converted to a `Student*`. That's because down-casting is not possible implicitly. In general, a `Derived` is a `Base`, so you can convert implicitly from `Derived*` to `Base*` (upcasting), but not the other way.

See e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) for some more information about up/down casting.

**EDIT** If you know your `Personel*` pointer points to a `Student`, then you can use `dynamic_cast<Student*>(your_pointer)` to access the `Student` features of your object. However, casts are in general a sign of imperfect design, and you should try to avoid them. In particular, how would you know what are the dynamic types of your objects in the list (assuming you get the list already filled by some other function)? You can use RTTI (testing `typeid` results then `dynamic_cast`-ing), but it is more than painful and not really recommended. It is much better to implement a common virtual interface and let the compiler deal with choosing the right virtual function at runtime.

Comment: virtual functions (might be, its still a pita) the better answer.  This answer is insufficient because Personnel *ptr will have no defined function for ptr->setBook(); when I need it.  It NEEDS to be a student for the whole functionality of the function to work.  But it CANT be a student to loop through the linked list.

Comment: Then either make sure the object is indeed a `Student` (`Personnel* p = new Student`), and use a `dynamic_cast<Student*>(p)` when you need the `Student` functionality of `p`. However, cast usage implies most of the time a design issue. You should try to avoid casting unless really really necessary. So try to think of some common functionality and implement a virtual interface. If there is not too much stuff in common, you should really think whether you want `Student` a child of `Personel`.

Comment: Conclusion: do you really want a list with multiple dynamic types from which you can choose non-common functions? I recommend not to, see the edit.